# Which journals make peer review history documents publicly available?

Tags: publications, peer-review, open-science

*Nature Communications* has had a [policy](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms10277) since 2016 that authors are given the option to publish the peer review history of their paper.

Are there other journals with the same initiative?

Comment: Authors can always do that. Personally, I started adding the "answer letter" to the reviewers as supplementary material to the paper itself.

Comment: Will that option for authors become compulsory?

Comment: The _[BMC Series journals](https://www.biomedcentral.com/p/the-bmc-series-journals)_ publish an article's review history alongside the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the biologies, I know of at least:

- [eLife](https://elifesciences.org/about/peer-review)
- [BMJ](https://authors.bmj.com/after-submitting/peer-review-process/)
- [PeerJ (Optional)](https://peerj.com/about/policies-and-procedures/#open-peer-review)
- [F1000 Research](https://f1000research.com/about)

as well as the BMC series mentioned in the comments. Thats just off the top of my head. I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 0):

The publisher [Cooernicus](https://publications.copernicus.org/open-access_journals/open_access_journals_a_z.html) has an open peer-review process, i.e. all peer-reviewer reports as well as the answers of the author(s) are published open access.

Answer (score 0):

The peer reviews for several highly regarded machine learning conferences (most notably the ICLR - International Conference on Learning Representations) can be found at https://openreview.net/. While these are not 'journals' in the strictest sense, they do have a peer-review process. The setup is however double-blind.

The website, e.g. for the [ICLR](https://openreview.net/group?id=ICLR.cc/2019/Conference) allows you to do the following:

- Read the reviews and the answers from the authors
- See the revision history
- Check withdrawn papers
- Add your own (anonymous) comment to any review